# How do I add up total numbers in a text file for python?

Tags: python

I've been getting stuck in the total_num() function as it gives the error

"ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''"

I know how to do it if its a defined list but if its set by the user I get confused.

```
def total_num():
    total = 0
    num_file = open("num_list.txt", "r")
    line = num_file.read()

    while line != "":
        num1 = int(num_file.readline())

        total = total + num1

    print total


def read_num():
    num_file = open("num_list.txt", "r")

    for line in num_file:
        print line.rstrip("\n")

def write_num():
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    num_file = open("num_list.txt", "w")
    num_consec = 0

    for x in range(num):
        num_consec = num_consec + 1
        num_file.write(str(num_consec)+ "\n")

    num_file.close()

def main():
    write_num()
    read_num()
    total_num()


main()
```

Comment: updated my answer showing a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are getting an empty string from your text file.  Look at this bit of code; you are reading the whole file into memory.

```
line = num_file.read()

while line != "":
```

Over here, unless you opened an empty file `line != ""` you are comparing the whole file with an empty string. So you will keep on looping until your `num1 = int(num_file.readline())` reads an empty line from the file.

You can find the solution if you look at your `read_num` method.

```
for line in num_file:
    try:
        total += int(line)
    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid data in ", line
```

By using `try except` you are able to handle the situation where the file might contain other invalid texts.

Comment: Or the ultra-short, ultra-fast version (for when the file actually has solely numbers or blank lines): `total = sum(map(int, filter(str.strip, num_file)))`; the `filter` can be omitted if blank lines aren't an issue.

Comment: great answer @ShadowRanger if you post it I will upvote. In my case I wanted to keep it simple because the OP is still finding his way.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the file in an odd way - namely, twice. `read()` puts the entire file contents into a string. If you repeatedly check whether there are characters in it, and then never change it, it will either not execute or loop infinitely.

Using `input()` to get a number will work, but it's better to use `raw_input()` and cast with `int()` for safety. Also, `xrange()` is a better practice than `range()` in Python 2. You don't need to keep a manual counter if you're already iterating over `range()`, either.

Overall, your code could be condensed to this:

```
def write_num():
    num = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
    with open("num_list.txt", "w") as output:
    for x in xrange(1, num+1):
        output.write(str(x) + "\n")

def read_num():
    with open("num_list.txt") as f:
        numbers = map(int, f)
        for number in numbers:
            print number
        return numbers

def main():
    write_num()
    print sum(read_num())

main()
```